# Is it possible to increment a variable name? or alternative

Tags: c#, winforms

This is my first post and I'm quite new to C# and programming in general, so go easy on me. I'll tell you what I want to do with my Windows form app.

If I press a button, a group box will be displayed and I can only create 10.

Now as I'm limited to my experience of C#, my thinking would be to:

1. on program start create 10 groupboxs named gb_ 1 to gb_10 and a variable named current_gb to monitor which gb has been created
2. on button press, An if statement will test if current_gb = 1, create gb_1 and increment current_gb++
3. on button press, An if statement will test if current_gb = 2, create gb_2 and increment current_gb++........etc

At present this is what I have. I thought of incrementing a variable name which you can't do and making an array of arrays which I can't find anything on.

Can anyone tell me a better, quicker way to do this please? or point me to a concept that can do this.

Comment: Just create a list called `groupboxes`, then put the group boxes in the list. Then you have access each element by its index. You mention that already. What's wrong with that approach?

Comment: The alternative is a collection of some sort - an array or a list comes to mind.

Comment: [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4995168/creating-dynamic-controls](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4995168/creating-dynamic-controls) you need a array